# can't user render in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following in a js.erb file:

```
  //add an image from the gallery to the mail later
  $('.uploaded_image').click(function(){

      var src=$(this).attr('src').replace("thumb", "medium");
      var location = $('#user_image_location').attr('value');
      $('#mailing_body').contents().find("[data-edit-img="+''+location+''+"]").attr('src', src);
      $('#image_form').html('<%=render "user_images/form"%>');
      $('[data-dismiss]="cancel"').click();

  })
```

I thought I could use erb in the js file to replace content on a page.
I get the following error:

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x00000103dea400>:0x000001059f2198>
```

If I remove the following line:

```
  $('#image_form').html('<%=render "user_images/form"%>');
```

it all works.

I thought I could use erb in js files with Rails 3.2

Why does this not work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly can use render (including any & all helpers, resources etc.) inside your .js.erb file (I just verified to be certain).

For `.js.erb` files to be processed the same way as your `.html.erb` files they must be placed inside your `views` folder (such as `app/views/<controller>` or `app/views/shared`), they cannot be placed in your `app/assets/javascripts` folder.